# No error/warning for multiple cout in one statement

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, cout

Accidentally I had multiple cout in one statement.

```
cout<<5<<cout<<6;
```

It displayed some garbage and I realized my mistake. But why no error or warning in such case? I am using codeblocks IDE with mingw for windows.

Edit: The complete code is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout<<5<<cout<<6;
    return(0);
}
```

The build message is

> mingw32-g++.exe -Os -pedantic -Wextra -Wall  -c "C:\Study
>   Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP Compiled\inputOutput\q1.cpp" -o
>   "C:\Study Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP Compiled\inputOutput\q1.o"
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o "C:\Study Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP
>   Compiled\inputOutput\q1.exe" "C:\Study Materials\C++\CPP Programs MP
>   Compiled\inputOutput\q1.o"  -std=gnu99   Process terminated with
>   status 0 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0
>   minute(s), 2 second(s))

Comment: What do you mean _no errors_?? [Check here please.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5383884462569794)

Comment: Can you show the whole code needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: There are *many* errors that the compiler is not required to diagnose according to the standard. It is entirely on *you* to follow the rules of the language and write correct code. The compiler usually tries to help when it can, but don't expect it to diagnose all errors. Just because something *compiles* does not mean that it *works*.

Comment: added complete code. @user0042 showed that there will be an error. But I am not getting and the result is 50x4899446. That means there is some compiler settings?

Comment: @Rajesh `-std=gnu99` looks suspicious for me. What's your g++ version?

Comment: gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2. I used default mingw came as part of codeblocks 16.01

Comment: Tried removing -std=gnu99 but still same issue

Comment: There used to be an implicit conversion from streams to `void*`. You're probably seeing that. It would help if you posted an example of "some garbage".

Comment: @molbdnilo: The output is 50x4899446

Comment: @Rajesh That's your 5, followed by `cout` converted to `void*`, followed by your 6. (0x489944 because pointers are printed in hexadecimal notation.)

Comment: @molbdnilo: I think I am clear now. So if I cout any function name, its address is displayed right? Since cout itself is a function, this is legal.

Comment: @user0042: How you are getting errors if this usage is legal? Compilers cannot differ much except in few  implementation defined cases right?

Comment: @Rajesh Newer compiler versions removed the automatic conversion to `void*`, hence the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should the compiler warn you about something that is perfectly legal? You are instructing the program to output the content of `cout`, which is legal, and will work.

I am not sure how the `operator <<` is defined for `cout`, but printing its address would be my expectation, so something like `0x489944` (or longer) seems just right.

With the 5 and the 6 around it, your output seems correct:  `5`+`0x489944`+`6` = `50x4899446`

Comment: Sorry, the result is garbage. That means it does not work and usage is illegal.

Comment: How do you know it's garbage? It could be the address of cout.

Comment: Now your answer make sense to me after looking at comments in original post. May be you can add little more explanation what happens if we output a function name or class name.

Comment: After looking at various comments and answers, I changed compiler settings and found that problem is mainly due to not using appropriate compiler. If C++11 is used, error (no match for 'operator<<') will be reported. But if C++98 is used, no error is displayed and it looks (void*) (cout) is printed as explained by @Aganju. In above case, -std=gnu99 was set and none was set for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **you** didn't **see** any errors

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is perfectly legal in C. This means that the compiler won't tell you that anything is wrong, as nothing is wrong!

This means that no error is displayed.

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine ... +1'ed your answer.